# Hibernate not equal example criteria

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate has example criteria:
For example:

```
Example equal = Example.create(mydbObject);
```

Is there a way to do the opposite,
For example:

```
Example notEqual = Example.createNotEqual(mydbObject);
```

or anything similar to create a "not equal" criteria. I don't want to go through each fields and not Restrictions.ne on it.

Comment: Do you mean to create a criteria that fetches all objects except the one specified?

Answer (score 13):

I'm looking for the same restriction method for "not equal" and according to the document, it's

```
List list = getSession().createCriteria("you.pakcage.hibernate.Example")
                        .add(Restrictions.ne("myProperty","blablabla"))
                        .list();
```

by this way you retreat a list contain all the `Example` object except those whose `myProperty` property is "`blablabla`".

Maybe not exactly what you what, but it achieves the same thing for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use it with `s.createCriteria(YourClass.class).add(Restrictions.not(notEqual));`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Your.class);
cri.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.eq("parameter", "test")));
```

--
Restrictions.not will be negation of the expression

Comment: Please provide some explanation on your posted code.