# Compare two tables of the same objects and select the different ones

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a joint table named EmployeeTask join by Employee and Task.

Relationship: Employee (ONE)----(MANY) EmployeeTask (MANY)----(ONE) Task.

So now I have an employee, and I use his **employee ID** to find all the ***employeeTask*** this employee has been assigned to, and subsequently find all the ***Task*** correspond to each employeeTask into a table.

Next, I get all the ***Task*** i have in the database into another table.

Finally, **I want to find out the list of tasks that has not been assigned to this employee**.

Tools I am using is **hibernate criteria** and the language is **JAVA**

Can anyone help, Please.

---EDIT---

This piece of code will give me all the **Task** I have for the given **employee**:

```
ArrayList<EmployeeTask> employeeTasks = EmployeeTaskDAO.getEmployeeTasksByEmployee(employee);
JSONArray tasksArr = new JSONArray();
for(EmployeeTask et : employeeTasks){
    Task t = TaskDAO.getTaskById(et.getTask().getTaskId());
    tasksArr.add(t.toJson());
}
```

The method to *getEmployeeTasksByEmployee*

```
public static ArrayList<EmployeeTask> getEmployeeTasksByEmployee(Employee employee){
    ArrayList<EmployeeTask> employeeTasks = new ArrayList<EmployeeTask>();
    if(employee != null){
        DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EmployeeTask.class);
        detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq(Key.EMPLOYEE, employee));
        List<Object> list = HibernateUtil.detachedCriteriaReturnList(detachedCriteria);
        for(Object o : list){
            employeeTasks.add((EmployeeTask) o);
        }
    }
    return employeeTasks;
}
```

The way of getting all the Task is quite similar to the above code sample.

Now I am literally lost in the way to find the rest of the tasks that are not been assign to this employee yet. What is the way I shall approach? Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the code that you have tried?

Comment: alright, give me a second

Comment: Would simple _not equal_ help? [ne info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774631/hibernate-not-equal-example-criteria)

Comment: Can you also share your models? Because what you want could be taken by using one criteria I think.

Comment: @B.K. Hi, sorry but which model are u referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of searching for the differences in two tables. I decided to store two different object array in javascript, and compare the two array to take out the uncommon ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say something without model, but you can try to use alias to join your three tables. There are [javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html) and some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726396/hibernate-criteria-join-with-3-tables) available.

To get unassigned tasks you can add *NotEqual* restriction @VytautasAlkimavičius mentioned.